# Methods of "Two-Way" Multidimensional Scaling (MDS)?

Tags: multivariate-analysis, multidimensional-scaling, procrustes-analysis

I just want to ask about the MDS. Below is the subcategory of the Multidimensional Scaling topic.

**Multidimensional Scaling**

1. Metric and Non-Metric Models
2. Methods of "Two-Way" Multidimensional Scaling (MDS)

I was tasked to report the second sub-topic of MDS which is the **Methods of "Two-Way" Multidimensional Scaling**. I don't have any idea about this topic actually, but when I try to surf through the internet, I found out one book which is all about **Multidimensional Scaling**. The problem is that I can't find the topic. But, I observed that there is this Section of Chapters entitled **MDS and Related Methods** consisting of chapters entitled *Procrustes Procedures*, *Three-Way Procrustean Models*, *Three-Way MDS Models*, *Modeling Asymmetric Data*, and *Methods Related to MDS*.

I know this could not be the **Methods of "Two-Way" Multidimensional Scaling (MDS)**. I'm not sure.

I just want a help on the description of the **Methods of "Two-Way" Multidimensional Scaling (MDS)**, or what does it talks about? or what are the possible sub-topics to tackle if any. Your help would greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about "two-way multidimensional scaling" but googling gives this:
[Two-Way Multidimensional Scaling: A Review](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/5613204)
and
[Classical Metric Multidimensional
Scaling](http://www.google.cl/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CCgQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.yaroslavvb.com%2Fpapers%2Fnotes%2Fdubin-classical.pdf&ei=wCxOUOi1KIiS9gSrzoCQDw&usg=AFQjCNGhXmdjC9x29I7LmgjjfFW_p4Rj3w&sig2=_HAdar1hEQSB03Vsjcr6RQ)

(But my impression from googling is just that this "two-way" thingy is an alternative name for what we just call MDS, referring to the fact that the input data usually is a matrix, thus "two-way". Evidence for this is the following link:

[Three-Way Multidimensional Scaling](http://srmo.sagepub.com/view/multidimensional-scaling/n4.xml)

which gives some generalizations.